# limit of an infinite sum of a random sequence of -1 and 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i$, where $y_i=-1$ or $1.$ Not sure how to think about this if there are infinitely many -1 and 1s. Any advice?

Comment: If a series $\sum_n x_n$ converges, then $x_n\to 0$, which can't happen here.

Comment: What do you mean when you write $x_n \rightarrow 0$, exactly?

Comment: I mean that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$

Comment: So you are saying that if the series converges, then the sequence $x_n$ must converge to $0$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: So I may just say that since our sequence $y_n$ does not converge (particularly, does not converge to $0$), then the $\sum y_i \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right

Comment: Thanks for the information; I was unaware of this fact -- do you happen to have a link to a proof of this?

Comment: Actually, what's preventing the series from converging to negative infinity instead?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid a giant comment:

Put $s_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. We show that $s_n$ converges implies $x_i \to 0$.

If $s_n$ converges, say to $s$, then so does the sequences $s_{n+1}$. Therefore, the differences
$$
s_{n+1}-s_n
$$
must converge to $0$. But $s_{n+1}-s_n=y_n$, and so $y_n\to 0$.

Comment: How do you have $s_{n+1}-s_n=y_n$?

Comment: Write out the sums and substract